# ultragrid filtered rows selection

Tags: .net, infragistics

I'm using Infragistics Ultragrid 2008, I have a button used to check and uncheck the selected column in the grid.

Even if the row filter is activated also when I click the button it checks the hidden rows selected columns too.

I want to set selected column to true only for the rows that are visible. Please help me with the code for vb.net 2008

this is the code I'm using now

```
    Me.lbltotal.Text = "0.00"

    Dim i As Integer = 0

    Dim nDx As Boolean = False
    If Me.btnSelectAll.Text = "Select All" Then
        nDx = True
    Else
        nDx = False
    End If

    While i < Me.UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows.Count

        Me.UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value = nDx
        Me.UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode)
        Me.UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Update()
        i += 1
    End While

    If Me.btnSelectAll.Text = "Select All" Then
        Me.btnSelectAll.Text = "Deselect All"
    Else
        Me.btnSelectAll.Text = "Select All"
    End If


    Dim r As Integer
    Dim sum As Single = 0.0
    For r = 0 To UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows.Count - 1
       If UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows(r).Cells(9).Value() = True Then sum += UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows(r).Cells(8).Value()

        Me.lbltotal.Text = sum
    Next
    Dim n As Integer
    n = Me.lbltotal.Text
    lbltotal.Text = n.ToString("###,##0.00")
```

Comment: Are you getting any specific errors or problems with your code? It'll help us focus if you have an idea of what the problem might be besides a generic "please help me with the code".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your intention is to apply your calcs only for the rows not hidden by the current column filter then you should change your loops in this way

```
For each row in Me.UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows()
    row.Cells(9).Value = nDx
Next
' Only one cell could be in edit mode, so this should go outside the loop '
row.PerformAction(Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridAction.ExitEditMode)
' same for data updating....'
Me.UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Update()
```

and this one 
(Based on your code above, this should be always true or false for every row)

```
For each row in UninvoicedMemosDataGrid.Rows.GetFilteredInNonGroupByRows()
   If row.Cells(9).Value() = True Then 
       sum += row.Cells(8).Value
   End if
Next
Me.lbltotal.Text = sum
```

However I am not very sure of your intention here. So let me know if this is what you are looking for or if I have misanderstood your intentions.